# How do I download only a little part of a big file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How do I download only a little part of a big file in Delphi? (like Download Manager)

For example, suppose I want to get the first 300 bytes of a 100MB text file over HTTP.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103.aspx

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is "Yes, it is possible.". There's no other information needed to answer it. Since that's probably not useful to you, you should perhaps [edit] your question to make it a little more clear what you're asking. :-) What, for instance, is "server"? And what exactly does it "support" (ftp, http, something else)?

Comment: http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/httpsend.THTTPSend.html#RangeStart

Comment: http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdRequestHeaderInfo_Range.html

Comment: I'm rolling back your last edit, because it's an entirely new question. Once you've received an answer to the question asked, it's improper to then edit to ask a totally different question. Post a new one instead, and ask there. This is not a site for evolving your code in your question. Ask a question, get an answer. Accept one if it helps you. If you then have a new question, post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> getting the first 300 bytes of a 100MB file.

Using WinInet library you can specify in the parameters how many bytes from the beginning of file do you actually need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103.aspx

---

In case you would later want some chunk from in-between you may investigate 3rd-party libraries. With those libraries you need to set HTTP request `Range` header - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

- There is no online help for http://www.overbyte.be/eng/products/ics.html but maybe in sources you would find support for it.
- There are numeric properties in http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/httpsend.THTTPSend.html#RangeStart
- There is string property in http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdRequestHeaderInfo_Range.html for `TIdHTTP.Request` object.

However the server may ignore this header. The library that you choose should check if server retirned `Content-Range` in HTTP Response and do something if it did not. Maybe download from very file start or maybe throw an exception. You should test those libraries and understand their behaviour in such a case.